# How do you add/edit code in Drupal?

Tags: javascript, hooks

I recently got thrown into a project to fix some problems with a Drupal 7 website for a client despite knowing nothing about it. First of all, is there a way to add my own custom PHP or Javascript code to fix some functionalities without having to create a module? Or are modules the only way of adding code? I find this quite frustrating as I do not understand how you would be able to immediately test things before deploying them. I made a Drupal account & it looks like I would need to make a sandbox, test it there, then install it to the website, but I feel like there must be another way. Is there a way I could just edit the current code on the website or another way to add code to a Drupal website without having to do all that? Thanks! And sorry for the novice question.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers!  This question is way too broad for this site.  You definitely do not need a drupal.org account and to make a sandbox to deploy code; that's for making modules available to everyone.  To add JS, you can add it to your theme: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/adding-javascript-to-your-theme-or-module.  As for adding PHP, first you should check if there is a native way to handle it in Drupal; a lot of stuff can be done in Drupal out of the box without needing to write PHP.

Comment: Your question is too general/broad, perhaps ask what you want to accomplish or what does it seem to not work and you might find people to offer possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Lee since your question is board I am going little verbose here, Yes ideally your custom code should go in as custom module. Since you got into an existing project check for any custom modules made by the previous devs, you can surely edit those. Usually dev encounter 3 types for modules on drupal

1. [Core modules](https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules): These modules are maintained at it best state since they are the backbone of the CMS. Nowadays they mostly maintain the code base for these modules. Come with the drupal install.
2. Contributed modules: These modules are mostly maintained by the D.O users these module usually bring a feature to the table. For example [notify slack](https://www.drupal.org/project/notify_to_slack) used to receive notification to slack once an element is made. These to be added separately. [Check how add contrib module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/extend/installing-modules).
3. Custom modules: This is were you should concentrate right now. If you think a site require a user/client level changes like extra pages, forms or adding your own JS code etc. you should consider adding a custom module. Follow this link to create a [custom module in D7](https://www.folio3.com/how-to-create-a-custom-module-in-drupal-7) also please note the directory structure.

Well that been said, why you shouldn't edit the core/contrib module's code base, you can do that but since these modules version controlled. Once a new version is released and added to your site you code will be overwritten. So a big no to this.

You shouldn't worry about the sandbox or most of the things inside the Drupal.org mostly these things are applicable for 1st and 2nd set of modules in my above list.

So my advice will be:

1. Create a local instance of the [drupal](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/local-server-setup/windows-development-environment/quick-install-drupal-with-xampp-on)
2. Add your project repo into it.
3. Check any existing custom module and edit it to your, if not create one for yourself.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Very detailed info, thank you!! This is actually exactly what I needed, google is also too broad when I've tried to figure this out and I could not find anything to answer my question. I really appreciate it!